# ssh-copy-id returns error "rootsh: bad characters in arguments"

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I'm trying to use `ssh-copy-id` in order to copy my `id_rsa.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in remote host.

I execute the following:

```
$ ssh-copy-id remoteuser@remotehost
```

But I have the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
remoteuser@remotehost's password: 
rootsh: bad characters in arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this server is using something called [rootsh](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/). This tutorial titled: [How to track Linux Shell Users activity?](https://www.hackersgarage.com/how-to-track-linux-shell-users-activity.html) covers it too.

> rootsh: bad characters in arguments

In these types of scenarios, you'll likely have to `ssh` to the server and then copy/paste the public portion of your SSH key-pair into the user account's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file by hand.

**NOTE:** your SSH key will typically be here on your local system: `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. So open it in an editor, copy it to your clipboard,  then `ssh` to the remote server and open the `authorized_keys` file (above) and paste the clipboard into it and save it.

Comment: That's exactly the trick! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: I tried also that command but it returns the same error. I solved with @slm suggest